# A question about converge locally uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Recently, I am learning functional analysis written by Philippe G.
> Ciarlet. In page 55, he gives a definition of converge locally
> uniformly and an example. I have some ideas about how to analysis the
> example, but I don't solve it completely. I will list the definition
> of converge locally uniformly, then talk about my problems.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ be a normed vector space. Then a sequence $f_n:X\to Y$ is said to **converge locally uniformly** to a mapping $f:X\to Y$ as $n\to\infty$ if, given any $x_0\in X$, there exists a neighborhood $V(x_0)$ of $x_0$ such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{x\in V(x_0)}||f_n(x)-f(x)||=0.$$

Example

$f_n:x\in(0,+\infty)\to\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}+\max(0,x-n)$, then $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f:x\in(0,+\infty)\to\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$.

Here are my ideas. When $x_0<n$, we can choose $V(x_0)$, such that $V(x_0)\subset(0,n)$, so for any $x_0\in V(x_0), f_n(x)-f(x)=0$, i.e. When$x_0<n$, we have $f_n(x_0)$ converge locally uniformly to $f(x_0)$.
**But** when $x_0>n$, for any $V(x_0)$, it can be written$V(x_0)=(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$, then $$\sup_{x\in V(x_0)}||f_n(x)-f(x)||=\sup_{x\in V(x_0)}(x_0+\epsilon-n),$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in V(x_0)}||f_n(x)-f(x)||=-\infty.$$

**So it is not converge locally uniformly when $x_0>n$, I don't know which step I went wrong.**

Comment: For each $x\in V(x_0)$, $\sup_{x\in V(x_0)}\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|\geqslant0$. So, how do you claim that the last limit is $-\infty$?

Comment: Because when $x_0>n$, I get  $\sup\limits_{x\in V(x_0)}||f_n(x)-f(x)||=x_0+\epsilon-n$, it is $\geqq 0$. But when $n\to\infty$, the limit is $-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

The variable $n$ is a dummy variable in some sense; the neighborhood, and the point $x_0$, do not depend on it. ($x_0$ may be bigger than $n$ when $n = 5$, but how about when $n = 500$? And if it's bigger than 500, how about when $n = 5000$?) In fact, $n$ should depend on $x_0$ and $V(x_0)$, not the other way around.

First you pick an $x_0$, and then you pick a neighborhood $V(x_0)$. *Then* you hope that, as $n \to \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in V(x_0)} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$. (And by "hope", here, I mean "show".)

One observation that may come in handy: for any $x_0$, $x_0$ is eventually less than $n$ as $n \to \infty$.